# What should I do when handling setting up a host for my client?

Tags: web-development, consulting, client-support, finance

So after a lot of learning, I've been making moves to get into making brochure websites for clients, but I'm doubtful as to what the best way to handle setting up the host financially for my client.

1. Should I direct my client to a host, have the person setup an account, and buy a plan I advise?
2. Should I ask the client for their info, and setup an account for them?
3. Is there anything else I should be taking care of in this situation?